# MySQL - how to change default charset to uft8?

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, ubuntu, utf-8, collation

I need to change the default charset of MySQL. I want the new database and all tables to use UTF-8. When I create django unit tests, the tests fail while creating the DB because it is set to latin1.

I can't do that in my.cnf. I use Ubuntu and MySQL installed from repository.

Answer (score 0):

```
create database `something` default charset=utf8;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# Alter your database
ALTER DATABASE database_name DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

SHOW CREATE DATABASE database_name;
CREATE DATABASE `zzz_test` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */
```